# Rails 3: Given an array of Clothes records, what's the cleanest way to associate them to a Store instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a

`Store` model that `has_many :clothes` and

`Clothe` that `belongs_to: store`.

Given an array of clothes that is associated with `store1`, an instance of Store:

`store1.clothes # [cloth1, cloth2, cloth3]`,

What's the cleanest way to associate the those clothes to `store2`?

I know I can just loop through all of them and push them, but that doesn't feel clean to me:

`store1.clothes.each { |c| store2.clothes << c }`. Any better ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
store2.clothes << store1.clothes
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer when timeout is over :)